# Taboos related to human condition

Tags: social-psychology, psychology, fear

It seems that us humans have built a lot of taboos surrounding questions involving our own condition.

For instance, the history of medicine is marked by conflicts between the willingness of scientists to better understand human body and a trend to oppose this, based either on religious dogma or (maybe?) a fear of what this could reveal.

Besides traditional religions, some people might be reluctant to understand the inner working of their body and develop an opposition to science on these topics.

Let's call this **the fear of learning about our condition**, now my questions:

- Are there some research confirming that trend besides what I mentioned above?
- Has this topic been studied from a psychological point of view?
- If this fear exists, what are the innate vs acquired aspects of it?

Comment: Whilst it doesn't provide an answer to yours, there's a question with answers that may be of interest: [What causes emotions?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/what-causes-emotions/13624#13624)